# Angular subscription is not executed despite an update to the observable

Tags: angular, observable

I have created an Angular service using `npm generate service`. This way, the service that is created, will be a singleton, i.e. the service can be used across the entire app. The service basically looks like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SelectRowIdService {
  private selectedRowIdState = new Subject<number>();
  selectedRowId$ = this.selectedRowIdState.asObservable();

  updateSelectedRowId(id: number) {
    console.log('updateSelectedRowId(): ' + id);
    this.selectedRowIdState.next(id);
  }
}
```

Now consider a table: Every time I click on a row, I am executing a method `onRowClick()`, which is calling `updateSelectedRowId()`. This method gets called with the correct id every time I click on a row, I verified this. The service's `updateSelectedRowId()` is called as well.

Inside another component, not the table, I am injecting the `SelectRowIdService` and subscribe to `selectedRowId$`:

```
  private selectedRowId?: number;

  constructor(private selectRowIdService: SelectRowIdService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectRowIdService.selectedRowId$.subscribe((id: number) => {
      this.selectedRowId = id;
      console.log('DemoComponent: ' + this.selectedRowId);
    });
  }
```

Now, this subscription is never executed and I just cannot understand why. Since I have verified that the service's `updateSelectedRowId()` method is called when clicking on a table row, I would have figured that the above mentioned subscription would be executed. I can only assume that this has something to do with the way I registered the service, that's why I mentioned this at the beginning of this post. Does someone have an idea about this?

Comment: You mention, you subscribe to the observable within another component, so first question, is the other component rendered while you click on the row? If so, check the 'ChangeDetection`within Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your second component appears elsewhere and after navigating away from your table, then this is the expected behavior. Basically, with `Subject`s, if you come late to the party, you won't get anything. Put in programming words, if you subscribe after the values have been emitted, then you won't receive any value.

In that case, you should use a `BehaviorSubect` instead.

Here is a [StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-subject-subscription-demo) that demonstrates both cases.

You may also find helpful [this article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/angular-component-communication-81e5e02c6cbe) on component communication.

Comment: you're right, it seems I just subscribed too late. Thx so much!